# Couldn't found cstdio.h

Tags: c++

All, Forgive I am a newbie in the C++ world , I was finding a copy file source code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195343/copy-a-file-in-an-sane-safe-and-efficient-way).

The first sample in the post used the ANSI C libary. So I would like to test this sample in my computer. But I found in my c++ project there is error says `Can not open the source file cstdio.h`. And I didn't found it in my `c:` disk. Should I need to install the `windows sdk`? BTW. My project is a WDK project. thanks.

Comment: `#include <cstdio>` not `#include <cstdio.h>`

Comment: Have you looked on your harddisk for that file?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: It's entirely possible that an implementation maps `<cstdio>` to a file `cstdio.h`. I don't know what you could learn from such a search.

Comment: Yes , My code is `#include <cstdio>` . and I already searched `cstdio.h` in my system disk. not found it . thanks.

Comment: I found the reason , After I installed the Windows SDK, now I can found the `cstdio.h` in my c disk. thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure your code says `#include <cstdio>` and not `#include <cstdio.h>`.

If your code says `#include <cstdio>` and your compiler is looking for `cstdio.h`, then you urgently need to find a better compiler.

Comment: Really ? My c++ project is created in the virtual studio 2012. And it is a WDM driver. thanks.

Comment: Really?? I have the same problem and I am running Visual Studio 2017!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C++, the correct header name is `<cstdio>` (not `cstdio.h`).

Comment: Although you should use cstdio, standard C++ provides 25 C headers, among which is stdio.h

Comment: @PlasmaHH Is my answer wrong ?

Comment: Upvoted, no idea why this was downvoted.

Comment: @MSalters I'm always on edge with C++ answers since I', very much a beginner. I know `stdio.h` is typically also available, but it doesn't put the right stuff in `std` (I think).

Comment: @cnicutar: That would be a subject of another question, but the content of the old C headers really weren't the topic of the question here. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1026367/15416

Comment: @PlasmaHH: That's true, but it should be noted that use of the C headers is deprecated.

Comment: Off course the code is  `#include <cstdio>`, any other reason ? thanks.