# Headers without cpp files and include ordering

Tags: c++, header, include

There was a highly rated response in [a question about header ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/614314/1079493) with the following suggestion:

> Good practice: every .h file should have a .cpp that includes that .h first before anything else. This proves that any .h file can be put first.
>
> Even if the header requires no implementation, you make a .cpp that just includes that .h file and nothing else.

Personally I've never had a problem with include ordering for headers that don't have a corresponding cpp file. What kinds of problems does this best practice prevent?

Comment: this could prevent a problem if two headers files have the same named definition in them (for whatever reason) or if one header includes another and the header doesn't have the `#ifndef HEADER_H #define HEADER_H` in it.

Comment: This practice ensures that each header has all of it's dependencies listed.  It's common for headers to use `std::vector` but not include `<vector>`, and never notice, since there's always a header included before them that _did_ include `<vector>`.  I've seen it a lot, especially on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The header file should compile on itself. ie. for testing make a .cpp file that just includes the header file.
2. The header file should be guarded by the pre-processor. if `#ifndef` etc...

Both these will ensure that the order will not matter.

Comment: These seem like the important things to me as well. It sounds like the "one cpp for every header" practice is redundant if you're already following cpp best practices.

Answer (score 0):

One problem it solves is allowing the .h file to be linted (at least by my lint tools). Without a .cpp doing an include of an .h my template code gets skipped.