# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type when time.h header is already included

Tags: c

I'm writing a header, timedate.h, which begins as follows:

```
#ifndef _TIMEDATE_H_
#define _TIMEDATE_H_

int timetounixtime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second)
{
  struct tm *time;
  time->tm_year = year;
  time->tm_mon = month;
  time->tm_mday = day;
  time->tm_hour = hour;
  time->tm_min = minute;
  time->tm_sec = second;
  return mktime(time);
}

/*...*/

#endif
```

And is then included in one of my main .c files as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "timedate.h"

int main(int argv, char **argc)
{
/*...*/
}
```

It seems to me that this should work since time.h is included in the main code before timedate.h is called.  However, when I make, I get the following errors:

```
XXXXXXXXXX$ make
gcc file2nav.c -o file2nav
In file included from file2nav.c:4:0:
timedate.h: In function ‘timetounixtime’:
timedate.h:10:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
timedate.h:11:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
timedate.h:12:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
timedate.h:13:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
timedate.h:14:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
timedate.h:15:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

Can you help me understand what's going on?  I note that if I `#include <time.h>` in timedate.h, the error goes away...But why?  It's already included in file2nav.c.

Comment: It's not a backtracking compiler.  Just include the files you actually need in your header.  Relying on include order is a horrible idea.

Comment: Header files are for function declaration not function definition.
Just think what would happen, if you included that file twice.

Comment: @EdS., I'm confused about why you have to #include <time.h> in the header file, but you don't have to #include <stdlib.h> or any other of the usual standard library headers?

Comment: `timetounixtime` should better return `time_t`.

Comment: @FrankHarris: You have to have the definition (or at least a forward declaration in some cases) of this things that you are actually using.  They must be in order. The compiler will not overlook and error in the hops that it will be rectified in the future.  If you create a `tm` or dereference a `tm*` in your code you must have the definition of `tm` beforehand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your file `timedate.h` you use

```
struct tm *time;
```

but `struct tm` is not defined yet. You need to include the header `#include <time.h>`.

A second problem in your code is that you're using an uninitialized pointer `time`. You can use a local variable:

```
struct tm time;
time.tm_year = year;
```

or `malloc` a pointer (remember to `free`):

```
struct tm* time = malloc(sizeof(struct tm));
```

A better practice, as Ryan points out, is to *declare* functions in `.h` and *define* them in `.c`:

```
/* timedate.h */
#ifndef _TIMEDATE_H_
#define _TIMEDATE_H_

int timetounixtime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second);

#endif
```

and

```
/* timedate.c */
#include "timedate.h"
#include <time.h>

int timetounixtime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second)
{
  struct tm time;
  time.tm_year = year;
  time.tm_mon = month;
  time.tm_mday = day;
  time.tm_hour = hour;
  time.tm_min = minute;
  time.tm_sec = second;
  return mktime(time);
}
```

You need to include all header files to make your program compile. [C++ Header order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614302/c-header-order) suggests one possible order:

- corresponded header file
- necessary project headers
- 3rd party libraries headers
- standard libraries headers
- system headers

In this order you will not miss any of your header files that forgot to include libraries by their own. (Thank Josh for this point).

Comment: I guess he thought it would be defined by having `<sys/time.h>` included in his main file.

Comment: @Kninnug, yeah, that's what I was thinking, and I don't yet understand why that's not the case.  My understanding is that the preprocessor inserts the text of time.h in the .c file, prior to the insertion of the text of my header file, so when the compiler gets to that part of the code, it should have already read the definition of tm.

Comment: @Yang also, I made the change to a local variable.  Not sure what I was doing there.  I need to go get a coffee maker for my office.

Comment: @FrankHarris: `<time.h>` and `<sys/time.h>` are different files.

Comment: A minor suggestion, if you include user headers first and system headers last in your implementation, then you are less likely to have order-dependent behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `#include <time.h>` in you `timedate.h` file because the function `timetounixtime` uses a struct declared in it.  That function needs to know what a `struct tm` is, and it doesn't unless you include `time.h`.  There are several other problems here though.

You need to allocate space for your tm struct as such:

```
struct tm *time = malloc(sizeof *time);
```

but since you're only using it in this one function, you should just be doing

```
struct tm time;
```

otherwise you're using invalid memory when you start assigning.

This header file should be separated into two files, additionally.

```
/* timedate.h */
#ifndef _TIMEDATE_H_
#define _TIMEDATE_H_

int timetounixtime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second);

#endif
```

and

```
/* timedate.c */
#include "timedate.h"

int timetounixtime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second)
{
  struct tm time;
  time.tm_year = year;
  time.tm_mon = month;
  time.tm_mday = day;
  time.tm_hour = hour;
  time.tm_min = minute;
  time.tm_sec = second;
  return mktime(time);
}
```

I suggest in the future you compile with `gcc -Wall`.  You'll get useful warnings like this one:

```
timedate.h:15:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mktime' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

^which means you are calling the `mktime` function without ever declaring it, another symptom of forgetting `time.h`

Answer (score 3):

You include the wrong header, it should be `<time.h>`, not `<sys/time.h>`.

`<sys/time.h>` probably simply doesn't define the struct you are trying to use.

Comment: The error still shows up, but I made the change to time.h anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Do not include `sys/time.h` but `time.h`.

Answer (score 1):

`time` also happens to be a system call.  I'll suggest changing the variable name `time` to something else so as not to cause a conflict with the system call.

Comment: Done.  I should've been aware of that.  Thanks!

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the time.h header from the header file because it won't know what the struct tm and mktime symbols are.

You would need forward declarations of those symbols in order for them to link properly when the time.h header eventually gets included from your source file.