# Instantiate a class within another class

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, playstation3

I'm new to C++ as to Qt. I have the following problem: I want to instantiate a CLEyeCameraCapture object within the Qt header public part, however I get heaps of syntax errors from CLEyeCameraCapture.h.

I get the following (german) syntax errrors:

> CLEyeCameraCapture.h(7) : error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor
>   Bezeichner '_windowName' CLEyeCameraCapture.h(7) : error C4430:
>   Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis:
>   "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.
>
> CLEyeCameraCapture.h(7): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen.
>   Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.
>
> CLEyeCameraCapture.h(8) : error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor
>   Bezeichner '_cameraGUID' CLEyeCameraCapture.h(8) : error C4430:
>   Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis:
>   "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.

...and so on...

Thanks in advance for any help. Here is my code:

qtdevc.h (header of my application class)

```
#ifndef QTDEVC_H
#define QTDEVC_H

#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_qtdevc.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <CLEyeCameraCapture.h>
#include <stdafx.h>

class qtDEVC : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    qtDEVC(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~qtDEVC();
    Ui::qtDEVCClass ui;
    CLEyeCameraCapture::CLeyeCameraCapture cam;

private:
    QPushButton *PushButton_startCam;
    QPushButton *PushButton_stopCam;
    QPushButton *PushButton_startLogging;
    QPushButton *PushButton_quit;
    QLineEdit *lineEditID;


// begin new code
public slots:
    int startCam();
    void stopCam();
    void quit();
// end new code

};

#endif // QTDEVC_H
```

CLEyeCameraCapture.h

```
#ifndef CLEYECAMERACAPTURE_H
#define CLEYECAMERACAPTURE_H

// Sample camera capture class
class CLEyeCameraCapture
{
    CHAR _windowName[256];
    GUID _cameraGUID;
    CLEyeCameraInstance _cam;
    CLEyeCameraColorMode _mode;
    CLEyeCameraResolution _resolution;
    float _fps;
    HANDLE _hThread;
    bool _running;
    std::string _participant;
public:
    CLEyeCameraCapture(LPSTR windowName, GUID cameraGUID, CLEyeCameraColorMode mode, CLEyeCameraResolution resolution, float fps) :
        _cameraGUID(cameraGUID), _cam(NULL), _mode(mode), _resolution(resolution), _fps(fps), _running(false)
    {
        strcpy(_windowName, windowName);
    }

    double GetRandomNormalized();
    bool StartCapture(std::string ID);
    void StopCapture();
    void IncrementCameraParameter(int param);
    void DecrementCameraParameter(int param);
    void Run();
    static DWORD WINAPI CaptureThread(LPVOID instance);
};
```

My Qt App (not cleaned up yet)

```
#include "qtdevc.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CLEyeCameraCapture.h"
using namespace std;

qtDEVC::qtDEVC(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect (ui.pushButton_startCam, SIGNAL( clicked() ),this,SLOT( startCam() ) );
    connect (ui.pushButton_quit, SIGNAL( clicked() ),this,SLOT( quit() ) );
    connect (ui.pushButton_stopCam, SIGNAL ( clicked() ),this,SLOT( stopCam() ) );
}

qtDEVC::~qtDEVC()
{
}

//get ID of participant
int qtDEVC::startCam()
{
    //qt part

    //ui.startCam->setText("Hi!");
    QString ID;
    //get qString Participant Number
    ID = ui.lineEditID->text();
    //convert to standard string
    std::string IDString = ID.toLocal8Bit().constData();
    //qDebug()<<ID;
    ui.lineEditID->setDisabled(true);
    ui.pushButton_startCam->setDisabled(true);


    //moved this to here from main
    CLEyeCameraCapture *cam[2] = { NULL };
    srand(GetTickCount());
    // Query for number of connected cameras
```

...

*edit*

including

> "#include " before "#include " in
>   qDEVC.h

solved the problem with the syntax errors in compilation, but now i get errors C2146, [C3210](http://bit.ly/1djvqcQ) and [C2602](http://bit.ly/18XDNpo) when tryin to instanciate

```
CLEyeCameraCapture::CLeyeCameraCapture cam;
```

what is the correct way ?

```
CLEyeCameraCapture::CLeyeCameraCapture *cam[2]; ??
```

Comment: Show us the minimal code which is causing the problem.

Comment: What is that `Q_OBJECT` in the first header file?

Comment: Posting everything won't solve things... Can you figure out what snippet is giving problems..?

Comment: Include "#include <stdafx.h>" before "#include <CLEyeCameraCapture.h>" in qDEVC.h may solve the compilation issue

Comment: olives hint fixed the compilation issue.thanks.
I cannot find the right way to instanciate CLEyeCameraCapture.
I get a `Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner
> 'cam'`

     `CLEyeCameraCapture::CLEyeCameraCapture cam;</br>
     //CLEyeCameraCapture::CLEyeCameraCapture *cam[2] = {NULL};??`

Comment: i get an  [error C3210](http://bit.ly/1djvqcQ) and an  [error C2602](http://bit.ly/18XDNpo) coming with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your compilation error,

```
Please Include "#include <stdafx.h>" before "#include <CLEyeCameraCapture.h>" in qDEVC.h.
```

for more info [Compiler Error C2146](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xbcaa9t.aspx)

Rule: Best practice to include standard headers first, then your own headers.[C++ Header order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614302/c-header-order)

Comment: thanks that helped but I'm still continuing to struggle.. see edit.

Comment: Please reorder as per the rule, stdafx.h, then Qt, then CLEyeCameraCapture.h, then qtDev.h ? and compile..

Comment: #include <stdafx.h>
#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_qtdevc.h"
#include <QString>
gives me the same errors as in the edit. i really think my construction of instanciating the CLEyeCameraCapture class is wrong
error C2602: 'CLEyeCameraCapture::{ctor}'is not a member of a base class of 'qtDEVC'

Comment: error C2602: Please replace "CLEyeCameraCapture::CLeyeCameraCapture  cam" to  "CLeyeCameraCapture  cam;"

Comment: then define default contructor CLEyeCameraCapture{}

Comment: in combination with using `#pragma once` in CLEyeCameraCapture.h this worked (defining a default constructor). I still can not find a way to globally access this variable in _qtdevc.cpp_

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36350/discussion-between-olive-and-refuzee)

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler has no clue what CHAR or GUID is. Include the necessary Windows header files to let the compiler know the definition of these datatypes. Probably including just `windows.h` could be enough.